# Android eclipse error with close/open SQLite database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, logcat

I use a SQLite database in my app. It uses the code below to check if there is some data in it:

```
if(tableExists(dbStoring.getReadableDatabase(), "storing") == false)
    {
        Log.i("infotable", "no data in table");
    }
```

In the LogCat of Eclipse i get sooooo many rules. Everything is working fine and i think it's not really an error, but it just annoys me.

The LogCat starts with this:

```
12-19 10:56:37.038: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13336): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-19 10:56:37.359: D/OpenGLRenderer(13336): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-19 10:56:37.359: D/memalloc(13336): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5235a000 size:9093120 offset:7557120
12-19 10:56:37.359: D/memalloc(13336): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5326d000 size:4608000 offset:3072000
12-19 10:56:37.459: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.609: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.709: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.819: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.879: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.919: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.949: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:37.999: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:38.109: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:38.420: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:38.570: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:38.810: D/dalvikvm(13336): GC_CONCURRENT freed 714K, 11% free 7074K/7907K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-19 10:56:38.820: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=41535], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.820: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=40834], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.820: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=53381], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.830: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=51410], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.830: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=33980], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.830: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=55242], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.840: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=42039], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.850: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=60272], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.850: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=42813], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.860: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=33060], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:38.890: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:39.010: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:39.180: I/global(13336): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
12-19 10:56:39.280: D/dalvikvm(13336): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1959K, 23% free 6965K/8995K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-19 10:56:39.280: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=37229], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
12-19 10:56:39.280: I/global(13336): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/192.168.10.201,port=80,localPort=34051], tmpsocket.getSoLinger()=-1
```

Then i get 700 rules with a constant repeat of there 3 rules (about 11 seconds non-stop writing), with exact the same information:

```
12-19 10:56:39.541: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13336): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.emmtec/databases , key = CecerejwDYtYF, flag = 6, file size = 18432
12-19 10:56:39.551: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13336): DB info: path = /data/data/com.emmtec/databases , key = CecerejwDYtYF, handle: 0x25ff138, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 827 M
12-19 10:56:40.682: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(13336): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.emmtec/databases , key = CecerejwDYtYF, handle = 0x25ff138, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
```

And it ends with:

```
12-19 10:58:42.821: D/OpenGLRenderer(13336): Flushing caches (mode 1)
12-19 10:58:43.151: D/OpenGLRenderer(13336): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-19 10:58:43.241: D/memalloc(13336): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53e33000 size:6144000 offset:4608000
12-19 10:58:43.251: D/memalloc(13336): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5440f000 size:10629120 offset:9093120
12-19 10:58:43.251: D/memalloc(13336): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x524fa000 size:4608000 offset:3072000
```

Method tableExists:

```
boolean tableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName)
{
    if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen())
    {
        return false;

    }

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = ? AND name = ?", new String[] {"table", tableName});
    if (cur != null){
        cur.moveToFirst();

        try{
            storing = dbStoring.getStoringFromDB();
            String Naam = storing.getKlantNaam();
            if(Naam.equals(""))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (cur.getInt(0) == 0) { //getInt(0) == 0 means 0 rules
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }       
    return true;
}
```

this is the method getStoringFromDB:

```
public Storing getStoringFromDB(){

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_STORING;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null); 

    Storing storing = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        storing = new Storing();

        storing.setVolgnummer(cursor.getString(0));
        storing.setKlantNaam(cursor.getString(1));
        storing.setLocatie(cursor.getString(2));
        storing.setSlaOvereenkomst(cursor.getString(3));
        storing.setContactpersoon(cursor.getString(4));
        storing.setHandtekeningString(cursor.getString(5));
        storing.setHandtekeningAchternaam(cursor.getString(6));
        storing.setHandtekeningVoornaam(cursor.getString(7));
        storing.setOpdrachtnummer(cursor.getString(8));
        storing.setTdMonteur(cursor.getString(9));
        storing.setStartdatum(cursor.getString(10));
        storing.setStarttijd(cursor.getString(11));
        storing.setEinddatum(cursor.getString(12));
        storing.setOmschrijvingStoring(cursor.getString(13));
        storing.setOmschrijvingWerkzaamheden(cursor.getString(14));
        storing.setProjectnummer(cursor.getString(15));
        storing.setBehandelaar(cursor.getString(16));
        storing.setFabriek(cursor.getString(17));
        storing.setMachine(cursor.getString(18));
        storing.setAantalUren(cursor.getString(19));
        storing.setAantalBijzUren(cursor.getString(20));
        storing.setAantalNachtUren(cursor.getString(21));
        storing.setSpoedeisendeDienst(cursor.getString(22));
        storing.setBedragOverigeKosten(cursor.getString(23));
        storing.setToelichtingOverigeKosten(cursor.getString(24));
        storing.setReiskosten(cursor.getString(25));
        storing.setReistijd(cursor.getString(26));
        storing.setStarttarief(cursor.getString(27));
    }
    db.close();
    return storing;
}
```

Is there anyone who knows where i should search the solution so that i dont get this data in the LogCat?

Comment: post this tableExists() method code.

Comment: why you are doing this *if(tableExists(dbStoring.getReadableDatabase(), "storing") == false)* why not simply *if(!tableExists(dbStoring.getReadableDatabase(), "storing"))

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur Ill post tableExists right now.

Comment: @JqueryLearner ye thats the same indeed, will do that, but that doesnt solve my problem unfortunately;)

Comment: @GeertG This is just a suggesstion,This will not solve your problem

Comment: storing = dbStoring.getStoringFromDB();What happen in this function?